# How to grab even numbers into a list in python 3 using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just starting to learn python and I know what I'm asking is so basic but I'll get to it anyway ,

```
# adding an If statements grabbing the even numbers
evenNumber = [num for num in range(0,11) if num%2==0]
evenNumber
```

and now I'm trying to do it the organized way using a for loop but I'm missing something :

```
#adding an If statements grabbing the even numbers using for loop
evenNumber = []
for num in range(0,11):
    evenNumber.append(num if num%2==0)

evenNumber
```

Appreciate the help and please don't mind my easy question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to point you to the error in your code, I have only rectified the part in your code which had the issue. Try this:

```
evenNumber = []
for num in range(0,11):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        evenNumber.append(num)

print(evenNumber)
```

However, the best way is to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

And you can use the third (optional) parameter of [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), i.e., `step` if you start your range with an even number and using a `step` of 2 ensures that you always get an even number.

```
evenNumber = [num for num in range(0,11,2)]
```

Or

Simply,

```
print(list(range(0,11,2)))
```

Comment: Super fast , thanks a lot I should of said "and including an If statement" that's what I wanted appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The range function has an optional 'step' Parameter, it defaults to 1 but you can change it to any number you want. e.g:

```
evenNumber = []
for num in range(0,11,2):
    evenNumber.append(num)
print(evenNumber)
```

Comment: It's important to note this only works if you start on a number that is even. If you change the 0 to 1 then it no longer works for checking if the number is even.